# How to implement “Clear” button in vue2-daterange-picker?

Tags: vuejs2, daterangepicker

Looking at vue2-daterange-picker examples at

https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker/#usage

I wonder how it is implemented with `Clear` button?

I need to make such button and empty values as default values (not 1 Jan 1970).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Your button needs to update the [`dateRange`](https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker/#props) object or rather 'reset' it to the default in this case.

Button

```
<button class="btn btn-info" @click="clearDate()" type="button"> Clear </button>
```

Methods

```
methods:{
    clearDate() {
        this.dateRange.startDate = null;
        this.dateRange.endDate = null;
    },
}
```

I am new to all this stuff, and I realise my response is some months after the question, but I hope that it helps.